# Flash projector and load external images

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, load, exe, projector

I have a Flash projector (.exe) file which load some images from local hard drive and move them. This application is called by a VB app at the startup (so it runs when you turn on the system). Everything works fine but there is a terrible issue. Randomly it **DOES NOT** load all images. I try to figure it out with disabling “Hardware acceleration” in flash (see: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/230262) and also disable “fullscreen”, but it happen randomly again!! … Please help. What I do ?

Comment: are you trying to load all the images at the same time? some code'd be extremely helpful

Comment: .. yes, it`s a `for loop` which call instances of a loader class.

Answer (score 0):

try loading every next image in the `Event.COMPLETE` handler of the previous one

Comment: I did that, looks ok but need time to test. Thanks.